# Better way to chain events together?

Tags: android, rx-java2

I have a piece of code that I am trying to convert over to rxjava.  I need to

1. create an object (asynchronous call)
2. add a phone number (synchronous call)
3. see if it exists in the database (asynchronous call)
4. if it doesn't, add it to the database. (asynchronous call)

Here is the code I've written.  I'm new to RxJava.

```
private fun createContactPhoneNumbers(email : Email, phoneNumber: PhoneNumber) {

    val single = SingleOnSubscribe<ContactPhoneNumbers> { e: SingleEmitter<ContactPhoneNumbers> ->
            val contactPhoneNumber = ContactPhoneNumbers(email)
            e.onSuccess(contactPhoneNumber)

    }

    var contactPhoneNumber : ContactPhoneNumbers? = null
    val completableOnSubscribe : CompletableOnSubscribe? = null

    Single.create(single)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map { t ->
                t.addPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
                contactPhoneNumber = t
                val completableOnSubscribe = CompletableOnSubscribe {
                    t.linkEmailAndTextTogether(phoneNumber)
                }
                t.doesEmailContactExist(phoneNumber)

            }
            .flatMapCompletable { t: Boolean ->
                if (t) {
                    completableOnSubscribe
                }
                Completable.complete()
            }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way it worked for me:

```
      Single.just(phoneNumber)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map { it -> it.doesPhoneNumberExistInDatabase() }
            .doOnError { t: Throwable -> Timber.e(t, t.localizedMessage) }
            .map { it ->
                    if (!it) {
                        phoneNumber.insertphoneNumber()
                    }
            }
            .doOnError { t: Throwable -> Timber.e(t, t.localizedMessage) }
            .flatMapCompletable { it->
                val params = arrayOf(phoneNumber.number, it.toString())
                GetNumberObservable.getNumberCompleteable(this@PopUpContactActivity, *params)
            }
            .subscribe(object : CompletableObserver {
                override fun onComplete() {
                    //do nothing
                }

                override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
                    compositeDisposable.add(d)
                }

                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                    Timber.e(e, e.localizedMessage)
                }

            });
```